# How to set another form to run as application in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I deleted default `Form1` from my project and added another Windows Form as `MyForm`().How to set this to run as application.
In fact I replaced

```
Application.Run(new Form())
```

to

```
Application.Run(new MyForm())
```

But its giving the following error:

> Error 1 The type or namespace name 'MyForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What error is it giving?

Comment: Show the code of the `MyForm` class, then it should be easily solvable :)

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'MyForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)....Is any other way to this?

Comment: MyForm is defined inside a namespace. In the `program.cs` file, make sure that you have added `using <namespace>;` at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the namespace of your new form and ensure that the application has it as a `using` directive.

The error means that the `application` class can't find the `MyForm` class, either because you didn't add the right assembly reference to the project (which could happen if the form is in another project), or because the form is in a different namespace (which could happen if you put it in another directory).

Comment: am really sorry..actually I created one folder and added Form to that...there I dint changed namespace...

Comment: @Sisya - You didn't intentionally, but Visual Studio adds the folder name to the default namespace that gets created when the source file gets added. You can either remove the directory name from the namespace of `MyForm`, or add the namespace to the application directory. Any what are you being sorry about?

Comment: That's a bit inaccurate. It's not the `application` class that can't find `MyForm`, it's the compiler. The `Application` class won't be looking for anything until Sisya manages to reach runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Providing that MyForm is a form located somewhere in your project or referenced then hover over MyForm() and press [shift + alt + f10](http://fernandof.wordpress.com/2007/03/16/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-every-developer-should-know/) , this should allow you to resolve the namespace :-)